# How to make Devexpress texbox that only contains digits and hyphen(123-7898)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I am using devexpress controls, I have a textbox which should only have digits in between one hyphen, for example 123-7898(7 digits and 1 hyphen) in same format.

When user enters first 3 digits automatically hyphen will enter on the 4th place and after that user can enter last 4 digits.

Please provide your suggestion.

Comment: What is the name of control? Search for keywords composed of control name and `DevExpress` + `Format` -> I think there will be a lot of info. `DevExpress` has fairly many documented pages and forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use JavaScript for this issue-

```
<script>
    function validatePhoneNumber(txtBoxObj) {
        if (txtBoxObj.value.length == 3 ) {
            txtBoxObj.value += "-";
        }
    }
    function getValue() {
        var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
        var a = phoneNumber.replace(/-/g, "");
        alert(a);
    }
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

</script>


<input id="phoneNumber"onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"   onblur="validatePhoneNumber(this)" onkeyup="validatePhoneNumber(this)" type="text" maxlength="8"/>
<input type="button" onclick="getValue()"  title="submit" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The DevExpress editors allow you to use masks during editing. Please try to set the `MaskSettings.Mask` property to `"###-####"`. In this case, a decimal digit can be left empty.

Go through the documentation to know that how to set these mask and a nice [online demo of masking](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/Features/MaskedInput.aspx) will let you know better.

Refer Masking feature of Devexpress editor controls in [Mask Editing Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument5741) documentation.